# How can I prove that this language is not context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

The language is $A =  \{a^{n}b^{n}a^{m} : n \geq 0, m \geq 0, n \neq m\}$.

I tried to use the pumping lemma. I chose the string s = $a^p b^pa^{p + p!}$ that is split in $uvxyz$ and must respect

$|vy| > 0$

$|vxy| \leq p$

$uv^ixy^iz \in A, i \in \mathbb{N} $.

I can prove that for some i and $v$ or $y$ is anywhere in $a^pb^p$, the language is not context free. But I don't know how to prove when they are in the last $a$. Whatever $i$ is, this can be pumped. So, I think I chose the wrong s.

Any idea how to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that while the language may not be context-free (and it certainly doesn't look context-free), the pumping lemma cannot be used to prove it.  It seems to me that you have put your finger on the difficulty.  Let $s\in A$.  Then $s=a^nb^na^m$ with $n\neq m.$  In the case that $n>m$ we can write $s=uvxyz$ where $$\begin{align} u&=a^n,\\v&=a,\\x&=\varepsilon,\\y&=b,\\z&=b^na^m\end{align}$$  Then for $i\geq0$,$$uv^ixy^iz=a^na^ib^ib^na^m=a^{n+i}b^{n+i}a^m\in L,$$ since $n+i>m$.

On the other hand, if $n<m$, we can write $s=uvxyz$ where $$\begin{align}
u&=a^nb^na^m,\\
v&=a,\\
x&=\varepsilon,\\
y&=\varepsilon,\\
z&=\varepsilon
\end{align}$$ and now for $i\geq0$,$$uv^ixy^iz=a^nb^na^ma^i=a^nb^na^ma^i=a^nb^na^{m+i}\in L,$$ since $n<m+i$.

Thus there is no string that we use can use for a pumping lemma proof.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) on the pumping lemma states that there are alternatives to the pumping lemma for proving a language is not context-free.  They mention Ogden's lemma and the interchange lemma, but I never studied either of these, so I can't be of much help.  (Or not until I read up on them, at least.)

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613082/using-ogden-s-lemma-versus-regular-pumping-lemma-for-context-free-grammars) of the use of Ogden's lemma, which may be of use to you.  I haven't found out enough about Ogden's lemma yet to understand the example myself.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you